# How to get the adjacency matrix from the dag?

Tags: r, directed-acyclic-graphs, pcalg

I know how to generate a DAG.

```
library(pcalg)
dag <- randDAG(10, 1, "er")
```

But now I need to get the adjacency matrix of the above dag. I guess there exists such a function but I don't know what it is.

The chatgpt give me the false result:

```
# Get the adjacency matrix from the DAG
adjacency_matrix <- amat(dag)

# Print or inspect the adjacency matrix
print(adjacency_matrix)
```

But unfortunately, Error in amat(dag) : could not find function "amat"

Comment: `as(dag, "amat")`?

Comment: @Axeman Error in as(dag, "amat") : 
  no method or default for coercing “graphNEL” to “amat”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `showAmat`

```r
library(pcalg)

dag <- randDAG(10, 1, "er") 
amat <- showAmat(dag)
amat
#>    1         2 3 4         5 6         7         8 9 10
#> 1  0 0.0000000 0 0 0.4144231 0 0.0000000 0.0000000 0  0
#> 2  0 0.0000000 0 0 0.0000000 0 0.0000000 2.0000000 0  0
#> 3  0 0.0000000 0 0 0.0000000 0 0.7542406 0.7771955 0  0
#> 4  0 0.0000000 0 0 0.0000000 0 0.0000000 0.0000000 0  0
#> 5  2 0.0000000 0 0 0.0000000 0 0.0000000 0.0000000 0  0
#> 6  0 0.0000000 0 0 0.0000000 0 0.0000000 0.0000000 0  0
#> 7  0 0.0000000 2 0 0.0000000 0 0.0000000 0.0000000 0  0
#> 8  0 0.3098213 2 0 0.0000000 0 0.0000000 0.0000000 0  0
#> 9  0 0.0000000 0 0 0.0000000 0 0.0000000 0.0000000 0  0
#> 10 0 0.0000000 0 0 0.0000000 0 0.0000000 0.0000000 0  0
```

Comment: But the doc says _"This function is deprecated - Use as(*, "amat") instead !"_ Edit: Oh but that doesn't work -.-

Comment: Yes, I am confused in the same way.  Warning message:
showAmat() is deprecated and only kept for backward compatibility.
 Please use as(*, "amat") instead But I cannot run  as(*, "amat")

Comment: Same. Perhaps we should file an issue.

Comment: in the mean time `as(*, "matrix")` does not issue a warnign

Comment: But I got a new problem. Look at the output of the matrix in your answer. The element [1,5] and [5,1] are both non-zero. Thus, this adjacency matrix doesn't represent a DAG.